# GitLab: prevent new users from assigning admin privileges to themselves

Tags: security, gitlab

I know this looks like a dumb question, but I just found out that, last month, something terrible happened to my GitLab instance: someone signed up on it and became admin himself, without my invitation, as I was the only administrator. So he wiped off every internal and/or private project inside of it, groups too (and I don't even know whether he had stolen all of them before erasing or not, I'm worried because they were proprietary code). How did it happen? Does [this](https://haxf4rall.com/2021/11/04/alert-hacker-exploit-gitlab-remote-command-execution-vulnerability-cve-2021-22205-in-the-wild/) have anything to do with, since the version was CE-13.3.0? If so, would version upgrading be enough to be safer, or should I make some particular configurations, such as disabling sign up page?

Comment: We won't really be able to help you with this - triaging what is fundamentally a security event requires in-depth knowledge of your system, authentication setup, and more. While there clearly is no intended way to self-elevate your privileges, you could have had issues with misconfigurations, you could have had issues with the DB that allowed the attacker to gain access, or more. There just isn't enough info we have to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to follow "[GitLab instance: security best practices](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/05/20/gitlab-instance-security-best-practices/)", which does include indeed:

> ### Ensure open sign-up is disabled on your instance.
>
> Open registration is disabled by default on self-managed instances with GitLab 13.6 and above installed.
> If new sign-up is enabled and your instance is open to the internet, anyone can sign up and access data.
>
> Administrators who would like to further restrict access on their instance can follow our [documentation on how to configure user access](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/sign_up_restrictions.html#disable-new-sign-ups).

Regarding the CVE mentioned, follow also "[Action needed by self-managed customers in response to CVE-2021-22205](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/11/04/action-needed-in-response-to-cve2021-22205/)", in your case: "[CVE-2021-22205: How to determine if a self-managed instance has been impacted](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cve-2021-22205-how-to-determine-if-a-self-managed-instance-has-been-impacted/60918)" (unless the log events have been wiped out as well).